# An Example about XNA UnloadContent

Tags: c#, xna

When i use XNA to make a game, I see the void UnloadContent, but i don't know how to use it, could anyone give me an example about UnloadContent and show it at the last game?
Thank so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're loading in any resources that need to be disposed, you would do that in `UnloadContent`. For example, you have a file that you want to keep the handle open for after loading it.

```
private FileStream _myFileStream;

private void LoadContent()
{
   _myFileStream = File.Open("myLevelDataThatIKeepOpen.lvl", FileMode.Append);
}

private void UnloadContent()
{
   if (_myFileStream != null)
   {
     _myFileStream.Close();
     _myFileStream.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Esentially, it is for content that you manage outside of the ContentManager.

Comment: While this particular action can be done outside of the UnloadContent method, this is a good example of a use case.

Comment: Agreed, it was one of those things where my mind went blank, this was all I could think of.

Comment: So, UnloadContent() used to save the information before close the game, and that all it can do? Tks for help.

Comment: @Septimus no, it's for disposing of objects at the correct time.

Comment: @Septimus UnloadContent() is just a method that's ran by the framework at a specific time. You don't have to use it, and even if you use it, you can use it for something else, depending on your need.